# Can't login on localhost Windows 10

Tags: magento2, localhost, windows

I've installed fresh Magento 2 on local machine, but can't login to admin, neither to customer page. No messages are shown about bad password or login if I try false login.

Console doesn't show errors on admin page, but some on customer login page:
[image]

System.log:

```
[2017-06-21 09:45:28] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_3c470299521325284ed2f872fb317d47b and handles default, adminhtml_auth_login: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2017-06-21 09:45:28] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_331b80c99f1d265b3f83441bdff2abf85 and handles admin-login: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
......
[2017-06-21 10:15:14] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_2dd32ce4e9a4da9f99b408194db562ca2 and handles default, customer_account_create: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
```

Edit: I have a bad feeling that's something wrong with server configuration, because I can't even login to Adminer for MySQL management...

PHP error log doesn't show anything.

Comment: use cmd to deploy static data using `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: The content was deployed. I suppose local server was not running as supposed. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using WAMP64, but changed to XAMPP and now everything is working.